# How save image from glide on button click in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-glide

I am showing images with glide into viewpager. If user like the picture than he save it on button click .

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_image, container, false);
    viewPager = (ImageViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    images = (ArrayList<Photos>) getArguments().getSerializable("url");
    selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");
    final Button save_img = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.save_img);
    final View view2 = viewPager.findViewWithTag("myview" + 
                                    viewPager.getCurrentItem());

    save_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                       saveImage();
        }
    });


    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);

    return v;
}
```

This is instantiateItem method -

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem( final ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);
        final ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
        imageViewPreview.setOnTouchListener(new ImageMatrixTouchHandler(view.getContext()));
        Photos image = images.get(position);

        final String img_title = image.getTitle();
        final String img_weight = image.getWeight();

        Glide.with(imageViewPreview.getContext())
                .load(image.getUrl())
                .asBitmap()
                .fitCenter().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(resource);

            }

        });
        view.setTag("myview" + position);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;

    }
```

now how can i get image resource from glide when user click on button ? I have a save image method that save bitmap in gallery.

Comment: check my answer if i understood you correctly hope it help you and if fit your needs please mark the answer as correct @Mukesh Soni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// inside instantiateItem make tag for image using position

```
Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position))
        .crossFade()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(myImage);
       container.addView(view);
    yourimageview.setTag(position);
```

//in activity define this varaibles

```
final File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SmartPhoto");
boolean success = false;
```

//in activity use this method to save images

```
public void SaveImage() 
{
        final Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        final String fname = "image" + n + ".png";
        myDir.mkdirs();
        File image = new File(myDir, fname);
        ImageView Imgv = (ImageView) yourviewpager.findViewWithTag(mPager.getCurrentItem());
        Imgv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Imgv.getDrawingCache();
        // Encode the file as a PNG image.
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            success = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.savedimage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.errorloadingimage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
        } else {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        }
    }
```